# TELERIK/ASP.NET - Cannot retrieve textbox text, from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a Telerik:RadTextBox control in my markup called txtName. I'm trying to retrieve the inputed value in the code behind with `foo = txtName.Text;` but var and txtName always show an empty string.

Any ideas?

**Markup**

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtName" Runat="server" Width="300px" />
```

**CodeBehind**

```
campaign.Name = txtName.Text.Trim();
```

I guess the code couldn't be easier. Basically what's happening is, when I click my 'save' button, there's a postback and the text in the RadTextBox just disappears.

**update**
Found the problem. My web.config file had a different version of the Telerik dll file that was actually in my bin folder.

Comment: Can you provide some more code ... where this statement is placed etc... Show the whole code-behind if it's ok

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually using "var" as a variable name, right? It's a reserved word in C# 4.

Comment: I'm using it here as an example.

Comment: I'd suggest using "foo" instead, but that's what I get for having C on a Sun machine as my first programming experience. Is there any chance you can post some code from your code-behind so we can see what you're actually doing?